# Why do iCode bugs appear to be used Unknown column guard_name

Tags: php, laravel, permissions

```
select * from `roles` where `id` = 2 and `guard_name` = web limit 1
```

and i added
 `use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;`
in controller and Model
in Controller

```
    $role = Roles::findById(2);
    $permission = Permission:: findById(5);
    $role->givePermissionTo( $permission);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the migration?

```
php artisan migrate
```

Please check the installation documentation: https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/installation-laravel